# Can Facebook notifications be sent from a not-yet-approved/test app?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-app-requests

I'm developing a Facebook app for the first time and am trying to get the hang of sending notifications to users.

I have a test app set up, and am using my own FB account, but no matter which permissions I grant the test app (manage_notifications, publish_actions, user_friends) I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error.

Using this Access Token debugger I am able to see that my Access Token as all three permissions listed above (manage_notifications, publish_actions, user_friends):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I'm sending the Open Graph request in my C# controller like:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/notifications?access_token=" + accessToken + "&template=hi";
request.Method = "POST";
```

But when I call:

```
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

I get the 403 error. Even stranger, if I hit the url directly in the browser I just get an empty response that looks like:

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "summary": [

   ]
}
```

As I said, this is a test app, so it hasn't been approved by the App Center yet. Is that why I'm getting this 403 error? Or am I doing something wrong in the code?

Lastly, is it possible to send notifications with an App Access Token? Or do you have to use a User Access Token?

Thank you!!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests

Comment: @CBroe

Followed the linked tutorial and sent this request:

var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/apprequests?access_token=" + userAccessToken);
request.Method = "GET";

But got this as a response:

{\"data\":[]}

Comment: Do you want to _read_ or _create_ a request now?

Comment: I want to create a new notification for a user.

Comment: Well then it’s POST, not GET, and you have to use your _app_ access token … have you even _tried_ reading the docs?

Comment: Yeah man, been reading the docs all week, when I use the "app access token" with the request instead of the "user access token" it gives me an OAuthException error code 102 saying "A user access token is required to request this resource." I'm just trying to push a notification to a user's Facebook account with the web request shown above, nothing fancy, but I'm getting 403 errors and empty responses from the API when I do. Does my app need to be approved by the App Center in order for it to send notifications? Am I using the wrong graph request (/notifications?access_token=...)? Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe - oh I see what you're saying, I think something got lost in translation... My question was can I send _notifications_ to a user from this app, not _apprequests_. Thank you.

Comment: OK, for notifications you can use the user or app access token. But the user has be a user of your app already.

Comment: That's what I thought, as per the docs, but when I use the app access token I get an error that says I must use the user access token, and when I use the user access token (granted by my personal FB account with the "publish_actions" and "manage_notifications" permissions) I get an empty response (as described above). So that's why I started thinking maybe this app needs to be approved by the App Center before I can start sending notifications from it, but I don't see anything in the doc's that specifies that.